# Python: How to insert into a nestled list via iteration at a variable index position?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, iteration, list-comprehension

I've been banging my head over this one for a while, so hopefully you can help me! So here is what I have:

```
grouped_list = [[["0","1","1","1"]["1","0","1","1"]][["1","1","0","1","1","1"]][["1","1","1","0","1"]]]
index_list = [[2,3][][4]]
```

and I want to insert a "-" into the sublists of grouped_list at the corresponding index positions indicated in the index_list. The result would look like:

```
[[["0","1","-","-","1","1"]["1","0","-","-","1","1"]][["1","1","0","1","1","1"]][["1","1","1","0","-","1"]]]
```

And since I'm new to python, here is my laughable attempt at this:

```
for groups in grouped_list:
    for columns in groups:
        [[columns[i:i] = ["-"] for i in index] for index in index_list]
```

I get a syntax error, pointing at the = in the list comprehension, but I didn't think it would really work to start. I would prefer not to do this manually, because I'm dealing with rather large datasets, so some sort of iteration would be nice! Do I need to use numpy or pandas for something like this? Could this be solved with clever use of zipping? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sadly unable to make this a one liner:

```
def func(x, il):
    for i in il:
        x.insert(i,'-')
    return x
s = [[func(l, il) for l in ll] for (ll, il) in zip(grouped_list, index_list)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

```
for k, groups in enumerate(grouped_list):
    for columns in groups:
        for i in sorted(index_list[k], reverse=True):
            columns.insert(i, "-")
```

Here, I iterate over the grouped lists and save the index `k` to determine which indices to use from index_list. I modify the lists in-place using `list.insert`, which inserts elements in place. Note that this only works when the indices are used from the largest to the smallest, since otherwise the positions shift. This is why I use `sorted` in the loop.